# Is there a way to pass existing view model as a data context to recently opened dialog window, when using autofac?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, autofac

I have a project, using **Autofac**. There is created a `BootStrapper` file that is called on application run:

```
public class BootStrapper
    {
        public IContainer BootStrap()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<FileDataServices>()
              .As<IFileDataServices>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<ScrapDataServices>()
              .As<IScrapDataServices>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<MessageDialogService>()
              .As<IMessageDialogService>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

And the class is called by App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

When the `MainWindow` is created, constructor creates instance of `MainViewModel`, that I want to use later:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel _viewModel;
        public MainWindow(MainViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = viewModel;
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
    }
```

In `MainViewModel` there is created `UpdateWindow` via simple `MessageDialogService`:

`var result = _messageDialogService.ShowUpdateWindow();`

And the `MessageDialogService` by itself:

```
public class MessageDialogService : IMessageDialogService
    {
        public MessageDialogResult ShowUpdateWindow()
        {
            return new UpdateWindow()
            {
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
                Owner = App.Current.MainWindow
            }.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault()
              ? MessageDialogResult.Update //if DialogResult = true;
              : MessageDialogResult.Cancel; //if DialogResult = false;
        }
    }
```

On creation I need to pass the existing instance of `MainViewModel` to the `UpdateWindow` as a `DataContext`. And I do not know how. Right now I only managed to create a new instance of the `MainViewModel` on creation of `UpdateWindow`, but it is not my goal, because in this window I am having controls that I need them to have binded with ViewModel created by `MainWindow`. Is there any way or approach to do that?

Currently I have only this:

```
public partial class UpdateWindow : Window
    {
        public UpdateWindow()
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            var vm = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're resolving MainWindowViewModel.

Register MainwindowViewModel as a singleton using

```
builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

Then add a variable of type MainWindowViewModel to the ctor of wherever you want to use it.

Resolve that - UpdateWindow is it?

The container should provide the same instance of MainWindowViewmodel it gave you for mainwindow.

Comment: As you suggested, I registerred in bootstrapper a singleton of VM `builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();`, and in constructors of my both views I am resolving it as follows: `var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            MainViewModel vm = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;` Unfortunatelly, there is still created a new instance of VM, when I open new window :( the instance of previously created VM is not used for the data context.

Comment: The container is an instance class. Meaning you need the same container all the time. Can't recall how you're "supposed" to cache the container in autofac. But you can cache a reference to the single instance in application.current.resources .

Comment: Awesome! I totally had no idea, that I can access any resources via `Application.Current`. In the ctor of the **UpdateWindow** I used `DataContext = Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;` to assign existing VM to the window context. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep,.  It's kind of a dictionary with a string key and object value.